# How do you get the number of columns in a SQLite File using PRAGMA?

Tags: sqlite, pragma

I've tried using `pragma table_info(test001)` however that just returns another table where there's a row for every column. My issue is that, how do I count the rows? I've tried using

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRAGMA table_info(test001)
and
SELECT COUNT(CID) FROM PRAGMA table_info(test001)
```

However they both error out. Does anyone know how I could get an actual numerical value using PRAGMA? I read the documentation for table_info but it didn't help in figuring out how to actual get a value from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
select count(*) from pragma_table_info('tablename');
```

You can find more info here:
https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html
in the section PRAGMA functions

Comment: I feel like an absolute buffoon. I looked at the link prior to posting the question but I just didn't know that the only thing I was missing was an underscore between PRAGMA and table_info...